# Exercise on projections

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f\in\mathcal{L}(E)$, the set of linear maps $E\rightarrow E$, where $E$ is a vector space of dimension $n$.

How can I show that there exists two projections $p,q$ (i.e., maps $p$ such that $p^2 = p$) and an automorphism $g$ on $E$ such that $$f=g(p)=q(g)?$$

Comment: Could you provide a bit more background? For example what is $E$?

Comment: @user50948 Is that enough ?

Comment: And $\mathcal{L}(E)$ is the set of linear maps $E \to E$? The more background the better!

Comment: @user50948 Oh sorry i thought it was the definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to think about rank-nullity. Suppose $f$ has rank $r \le n$. Then its kernel has dimension $(n-r)$ and its range has dimension $r$. Since $g$ is an automorphism, then if

$$f = g \circ p$$
then $p$ must somehow capture the fact that $f$ has a kernel (might not be injective). And

$$ f = q \circ g$$
means that $q$ must somehow capture the fact that $f$ might not be surjective.